# How should I use an async future list in another async function?

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I'm trying to fetch a url list from a website with an async method.
After I get the list of urls, I tried use the urls in another async method.

Here is for getting the urls:

```dart
void _getData() async {
    final response =
        await http.get('https://www.whateverurl');
    print(response.statusCode);
    dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
    final elements2 = document.getElementsByClassName('image-card-wrapper');
    setState(() {
      //fetches links as /tiger /catalina etc.
      urlList = elements2.map((element) async {
        url = 'https://www.whateverurl' +
            element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].attributes['href'];
        print(element.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].attributes['href']);
        return url;
      }).toList();
        await _tryFetch(urlList);
    });
  }
```

It is successful. I can get the list. What I couldn't solve is : I tried to use this url list in another async function to get the specific technic info of every item.

```dart
 _tryFetch(List urls) async {
    String e = '';
    for (var item in urls) {
      try {
        final response2 = await http.get(item);
        dom.Document document2 = parser.parse(response2.body);
        final elements = document2.getElementsByClassName('sqs-block-content');
        elements.forEach((element) {
          if (element.getElementsByTagName('li').isNotEmpty) {
            List a = element.getElementsByTagName('li');
            print(a.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
              var z = a[i].children[0].text ?? '...';
              e = e + z.toString();
            }
          }
          setState(() {
            tekniskInfo.add(e);
            print(tekniskInfo);
          });
        });
      } on Exception catch (_) {
        print('elele');
      }
    }
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    _getData();
    super.initState();
  }
```

In my Scaffold, when try to use this **teksniskInfo[index]** in ListView.builder;
It throws error: **Future String is not sub of String...**

I tried to add a button to use _tryFetch() function. It works when I push the button. But problem is, when I navigate to the page first time it throws the error that I mentioned up.

To summarise; how can I use a future list in another future function?

Comment: try adding await to urlList. await _tryFetch(await urlList); or just remove the async in elements2.map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreword

1. The async and await keywords support asynchronous programming, letting you write asynchronous code that looks similar to synchronous code.
2. Each function marked as `async` returns Future

So the way to use async function(returns Future) in another async function is to `await` result of function

```
Future<String> foo() => ...;

Future<void> bar() {
  final String = await foo();
}

...
await bar(); //somewhere else    
...
```

Back to your code

I see error in `_getData()` - you can't make the function argument of setState(fn) async, so next is errorneous code

```
setState(() { 
  await foo(); //Error! - you can't await Future in synchronous function
});
```

You can mitigate this with calling `setState` after async results

```
void _getData() async {
  ...
  await _tryFetch();
  ...
  setState((){});
}
```

For now you need to wait each Future in list (last await)

```
List<Future<String>> urlList = elements2.map((element) async {...

_tryFetch(List urls) async {
  String e = '';
  for (var item in urls) {
    try {
      final response2 = await http.get(await item); //each is Future<String> you need to wait
```

But there is no need to put `async` anonymous function to map(...)

And result will be `List<String> urlList = elements2.map((element) {...` and no need to await each list item

Feel free to reach me in comments